# How to have a Division with only 1px height and image in it. without any margin and padding

Tags: css

When I am creating a Division, it is taking by default height as around `20px`. I want to have a division with image in it which is having only `1px` height. It is a line.

This is my CSS for the Image.

```
#LineImage {
    height: 1px;
    font: semibold 1px Helvetica Neue;
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#Line {
    background-color: #262a2e;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And here is my html division

```
<div id="Line">
  <img id="LineImage" src="/MyLoc/Images/line.png">
</div>
```

Please help me out to have division with only `1px` height and image in it. `top`, `bottom`, `padding` and `margin` should be `0`.

Comment: Remove the spaces, these might render to text and make the div higher than wanted.

Comment: AFAIK, no image will be visible in `1px` height container.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:1px` to the div.

CSS:

```
#LineImage
{
height:1px;
font: semibold 1px Helvetica Neue;
width:100%;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
#Line {
    height:1px;
background-color: #262a2e;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj9bd4o8/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response. Can i have a fade out on both sides (left and right) for this divisions. if yes, how can i achieve this .??